# Can't change custom UIFont size on the UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uifont

I have a button that I use custom UIFont to display text on. The font loads correctly and is correctly applied to the button title. My problem is I can't seem to be able to change font size:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(63.0, 200.0, 194.0, 60.0);
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"My-Font" size:8.0f];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

No matter what I put in for font size, I get some default size. On the other hand, if I do something like this:

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:32.0f];
```

I get size 32 font, however, of course, I don't get my custom font.
So, how do I set a size for custom font?

(I use Xcode 4.6.3)

Comment: I guess that "MyFont" in `fontWithName`is null...
Simple and quickTest :
`UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:8.0f]; NSLog(@"MyFont: %@", myFont);`

Comment: @Larme yes, it is... hmmm, why would it be? I can see it under Bundle Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources. Also, it looks like the font on label changes

Comment: Make sure your font name is correct. The font name is not always the file name of the font.

Comment: @HAS i double checked that (from Finder -> font -> 'space' [for preview]), it matches what I am looking for

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: Open your font with _Font Book_ app, then look up for `PostScript name` property.

Comment: @logixologist I presume this looks for default/ios provided fonts. I have a custom .ttf file

Comment: @mike.tihonchik I didnt think you could use a font outside of what ios provides. could this be your issue?

Comment: This might be a little overkill but I did this and its very helpful: http://www.ios-dev-blog.com/uiviewcontroller-with-all-fonts-available-in-ios/

Comment: @logixologist Doubt it... OS 3.2 and later support this. Straight from the What's New in iPhone OS 3.2 doc:

Custom Font Support
Applications that want to use custom fonts can now include those fonts in their application bundle and register those fonts with the system by including the UIAppFonts key in their Info.plist file. The value of this key is an array of strings identifying the font files in the application’s bundle. When the system sees the key, it loads the specified fonts and makes them available to the application.

Comment: I stand corrected! Sorry that did not help you solve your problem

Comment: @mike.tihonchik: Ok. The name used for `fontWithName` is something I never understood. It's a pain in the $ss when I needed a custom font... I don't remember how I get the "real nworking name", but I'll 've check a lot of SO already questions... I don't see if you added your font in the info.plist.

Comment: @Larme yes, I have added my fonts into info.plist (in array fashion). I also selected 'copy fonts' when dragging them to XCode project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, it turned out to be my Mac. When I gave my friend to install them, he had no issues. 
My Mac is on the old side, so maybe this was the reason. Here are the specs:

```
**Mac:** MacBook Pro 15" (Late 2008)
**Processor:**  2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
**Memory:** 4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
**Graphics:** NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT 256 MB
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your UIFont object isn't getting created correctly and is returning `nil`.

This is the best tutorial I have found on putting in custom fonts.  Good luck ;)

http://refactr.com/blog/2012/09/ios-tips-custom-fonts/ ([Archived Version](https://web.archive.org/web/20170331204257/https://refactr.com/blog/2012/09/ios-tips-custom-fonts/))

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *fontsByFamilyName = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES] autorelease]];

    NSArray *familyNames = [[UIFont familyNames] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    for (NSString *aFamilyName in familyNames) {
        NSArray *fontNames = [[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:aFamilyName] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        [fontsByFamilyName setObject:fontNames forKey:aFamilyName];
        NSLog(@"fonts :%@", fontsByFamilyName);           
    }
```

Look for the "iOS" name of your font... I found my cusom ones with this method. If you don't, let's check how you added your font (maybe a action forgotten).
Source: http://forgecode.net/2010/08/uifont-name-grabber/

Comment: yep, I don't see my font in the list

Comment: Ok. So is your font in Build Phases/Copy Bundle Ressources, and in Font Provided by application in the MyAppl-Info.plist file.

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall your font? Like in the link given by @Matt Mc?

Comment: i think the font file that I have is actually wrong... I will need to read up on web fonts vs. desktop fonts

Answer (score 2):

To get the font name you have to pass in `fontWithName:size:`, open your font with *Font Book* app, then look up for the `PostScript name` property. Make shure you have added it to `Info.plist` file too.

Comment: all the above done, font appears throughout, and checked in FontBook... I think my issue is actually incorrect font type (web font vs. desktop font)

Answer (score -1):

passing in 'nil' for 'My-Font' enables text resizing for the default font - without having to know what the actual font being used is:

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:nil size:10.0f];
```